# R create a dataframe from variable length vectors

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

This is do with sports and i'll simplify my problem a little to explain. I have a vector, one row with 3 elements.

1. RaceID
2. RaceName
3. HorseNo

Raceid is one entry X1079
RaceName is one entry "Derby"
HorseNo is a vector and has 7 entries 1:7 for the horses entered in the race.

How can i manipulate this vector to a dataframe 7 x 3, so that there is one observation per Horseno (and raceid, racename is repeated 7 times on each row)?

Many thanks,

Comment: `RaceID  = rep(RaceID, length(HorseNo))`

Answer (score 0):

With

```
df1 <- expand.grid(RaceID = "X1079", RaceName = "Derby", HorseNo = 1:7)
```

you get:

```
  RaceID RaceName HorseNo
1  X1079    Derby       1
2  X1079    Derby       2
3  X1079    Derby       3
4  X1079    Derby       4
5  X1079    Derby       5
6  X1079    Derby       6
7  X1079    Derby       7
```